# How can i place my Spinner(DropDown) on top of a WebView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-webview, android-spinner

im new to Android development.
I think i got kinda the basics, but after 8 workhours of not getting my DropDown above my WebView, i tought i gotta ask.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val languages = resources.getStringArray(R.array.array1)

     val webview = WebView(this)
    setContentView(webview)
     webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
   webview.loadUrl("http://localhost/test/neu/index.php")


    // access the spinner
    val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner1)
    if (spinner != null) {
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages)
        spinner.adapter = adapter

        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object :
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>,
                                        view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                    getString(R.string.selected_item) + " " +
                            "" + languages[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                // write code to perform some action
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It does what it's supposed to do, the only thing is it places the Spinner below the WebView. If i comment out line 5-8 inside the onCreate(), it shows me a white screen with only the Spinner.

Looking for Answers to this question just brings me SO threads on how to make a Progress bar, which i dont get, but w/e.
Thanks in advance

My Manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ttermscannerandroid51">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TTermScannerAndroid51">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

at last my activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.377"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    </WebView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest your `Spinner` inside the `Webview`, just give it constraints so it sits where you want.

I'm not sure if you mean you want it *vertically above* the WebView, or *overlaid* - if it's above, constrain the top of the spinner to the top of the parent, and the top of the webview to the bottom of the spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/WebView"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spinner1"/>
```

If you want it overlaid, constrain the top of the spinner to the top of the webview, etc:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/WebView"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/WebView"/>
```

Now the spinner is relative to the WebView, and you can use margins, constraints etc to position it relative to the WebView's edges. When overlaying, order matters, but you can give it an `elevation` value to explicitly move it higher, so it displays over the WebView

Comment: Thanks alot for your Help. What i meant to ask, was "How do i get the Spinner placed on top of the WebView". The Fact that i have to put it outside the webView, just never came to my mind. Thanks alot. I put it behind the WebView, now i can see it in my Design View. So 1 step closer, i still cant see the Spinner itself once i start the app. 

My WebView starts and ends with a  "<WebViev" Tag. The Spinner starts with a Tag as well but only closes with a greater Than sign. Is that on purpose? Thanks again in Advance :)

Comment: Something else i noticed now, if i move the Spinner withing my WebView, it places it automatically into my WebView. Even after adding constraints. Strange :/

Comment: @BusyArbeiten It's definitely not adding it *into* the WebView, a Spinner is a native widget and WebViews display web content, you'd have to create a spinner in HTML etc to get it *inside* the WebView. Check your constraints, and remember to give it an `elevation` value to raise it above the WebView if necessary. If the Spinner's behind, you won't see it. And the closing tag thing is an XML feature - you have an opening and closing tag for things, but if there's nothing *inside* those tags (no children) you can just have the opening tag, ending with ``/>`` - it's like shorthand for closing it